# my code to find the number of vowels doesnt work

Tags: ruby

```
def count_vowels(string)
  count_vowels = 0
  my_vowels = ["a" "e" "i" "o" "u"]
  idx = 0
  while idx < string.length
    gdx = 0
    while gdx < my_vowels.length
      if string[idx] == my_vowels[gdx]
        count_vowels = count_vowels + 1
      else
        gdx = gdx + 1
      end
    end
    idx = idx + 1
  end

  return count_vowels
end
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Despite everything, you need to separate the elements in your array with comma.

Comment: check out http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-26

Comment: What do you mean by _"doesn't work"_? Any errors or unexpected results?

Comment: You could use Ruby `'vowels'.count('aeiou') #=> 2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while gdx < my_vowels.length
      if string[idx] == my_vowels[gdx]
        count_vowels = count_vowels + 1
      else
        gdx = gdx + 1
      end
end
```

should be:

```
while gdx < my_vowels.length
          if string[idx] == my_vowels[gdx]
            count_vowels = count_vowels + 1
            gdx = gdx + 1
          else
            gdx = gdx + 1
          end
end
```

As you are not advancing your gdx-counter after finding a vowel. So it ends
up in a loop after finding the first vowel.

Also fixing the array declaration, the working code could be something like this:

```
def count_vowels(string)
  count_vowels = 0
  my_vowels = ["a", "e", "i","o","u","y"]
  idx = 0
  while idx < string.length
    gdx = 0
    while gdx < my_vowels.length
      if string[idx] == my_vowels[gdx]
        count_vowels = count_vowels + 1
        gdx=gdx+1
      else
        gdx = gdx + 1
      end
    end
    idx = idx + 1
  end
```

Comment: Also, you could just advance gdx outside/after the if-block, assuming you want to advance in any/every case.

Comment: It seems inefficient to repeat `gdx = gdx + 1` in both branches...

Comment: still it shows the number of vowel as 0

Comment: Did you fix your vowel array? If you are not white spacing the vowels, you need to use a delimiter.

Comment: And yes, advancing "gdx" in both if cases is a bit noobeish, if you are going to do it no matter what happens and not planning to add any magic inside the blocks. Hence I suggested you can do it outside the block as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
def count_vowels(str)
  str.downcase.count("aeiou")
end

count_vowels("All the king's horses and all the king's men...")
  #=> 10
```

Comment: @Simple, yes, of course. Also I should have used `count` rather than `reduce`. Fixed both.

Comment: If you're using `count` then maybe... `str.count('aeiouAEIOU')` or `str.downcase.count('aeiou')`.

Comment: @Sagar, another "of course". I made the change. I am but a scribe!

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach

```
def count_vowels(string)
  ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'].inject(0) { |sum, el| sum += string.downcase.count(el) }
end
```

Please note I did `downcase` for input string to reduce iterations amount. If you have another logic - just remove it.